# How to use TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder in Apache Ignite .Net

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy an Apache Ignite cluster in Kubernetes. The documentation suggests using TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder to facilitate the Ignite node discovery in a Kubernetes environment. However, I could not find this class in Apache Ignite for .Net. Is it migrated to .Net at all? If not, how can I use in my Net application? I am not very much familiar with Java.

If it is not possible, is there an alternative approach to implement node discovery in the Kubernetes environment without using TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder? Multicast is not available in Azure Virtual Network.

The range of available IPs in my Kubernetes subnet is 1000+ addresses so using TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder would not be very efficient. I tried to reduce FailureDetectionTimeout to 1 sec on my local PC to make it more efficient but Ignite generates a bunch of the "critical thread blocked" exception, allegedly each time when an endpoint is found unavailable. So I had to get rid of FailureDetectionTimeout.

I am using Azure Kubernetes Service and Apache Ignite 2.7 for Net. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine Java-based (Spring XML) configuration with .NET configuration.

1. Configure `TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder` in Spring XML file (see https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-ip-finder)
2. In .NET, set `IgniteConfiguration.SpringConfigUrl` to point to that file

The way it works is Ignite loads Spring XML first, then applies any custom config properties that are specified on .NET side.

Comment: I've created the config file, copied the class ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar and others from ignite-kubernetes directory. Now when I start the application, I get a jar not found error. Everything else in Ignite works successfully, other Ignite classes are being found. Should I specify the CLASSPATH elsewhere when I use the spring conf.? 

---
Failed to instantiate configuration from Spring XML:
 ...
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH)

Comment: It has turned out that I need to specify the full path to ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar, including file name, in IgniteConfiguration#JvmClasspath in addition to IgniteHome.

Comment: @AlexAvrutin setting `JvmClasspath` can be avoided if you place `ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar` next to all other jar files to the output directory of your project, into the `Libs` folder.

Comment: I did exactly so but it did not help. I have another problem related to this one (Ignite node wouldn't start) for which I am going to create another issue.

Comment: Added another q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408181/apache-ignite-net-node-would-not-start-when-a-spring-configuration-file-is-used