# Apache Ignite .Net node would not start when a Spring configuration file is used

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite .Net v2.7. While resolving another issue ([How to use TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder in Apache Ignite .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388489/how-to-use-tcpdiscoverykubernetesipfinder-in-apache-ignite-net/55392149)) I've added a sprint configuration file where the Kubernetes configuration is specified. All other configuration goes in the C# code.

The content of the config file is below (taken from the docs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
            <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The C# code which references the file is as follows:

```
var igniteConfig = new IgniteConfiguration
        {
            SpringConfigUrl = "./kubernetes.config",
            JvmClasspath = string.Join(";",
                new string[] {
                    "ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar",
                    "jackson-core-2.9.6.jar",
                    "jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar"
                }
                .Select(c => System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Libs", c)))}
```

The Ignite node starts fine locally but when deployed to a Kubernetes cluster, it fails with this error:

```
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/app/./kubernetes.config]
Mar 28, 2019 10:43:55 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1bc6a36e: startup date [Thu Mar 28 22:43:55 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy

Unhandled Exception: Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Java exception occurred [class=java.lang.NoSuchFieldError, message=logger] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Com
mon.JavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:727)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:751)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:809)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.configuration(PlatformIgnition.java:153)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:68)

   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.Env.ExceptionCheck()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedUtils.IgnitionStart(Env env, String cfgPath, String gridName, Boolean clientMode, Boolean userLogger, Int64 igniteId,
 Boolean redirectConsole)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
   at UtilityClick.ProductService.Initializer.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Init>b__1(IServiceProvider sp) in /src/ProductService/Initializer.cs:line 102
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope sc
ope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at UtilityClick.ProductService.Initializer.Init(IServiceCollection serviceCollection) in /src/ProductService/Initializer.cs:line 123
   at UtilityClick.ProductService.ApiStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /src/ProductService/ApiStartup.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at UtilityClick.ProductService.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/ProductService/Program.cs:line 14
```

Do you have any idea why it might happen? Which logger is it complaining about?

Kubernetes is running Linux containers, locally I'm using Windows 10.

Two more observations:

1. When I specify the config file name as `kubernetes.config`, the node launches successfully on local but in Kubernetes it fails with an error which suggests that the URL "kubernetes.config" is missing the schema part.
2. JvmClasspath: I have to add "ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar", otherwise the JAR is not found although it is located in the same dir as the rest of the Ignite classes. Adding the next two entries does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have different versions of `spring-core` and `spring-beans` in your Java classpath for some reason. There's no reason for them to not match exactly. I think it should print full classpath somewhere, you can look it up.

In 2.7 Apache Ignite ships differing version of Spring libs in `ignite-spring-data_2.0` submodule. Maybe it got into your classpath by accident? Please remove that dir for good - you'll not need it when using .Net.

*UPD:* With your reproducer project, it looks like I'm starting successfully:

```
Directories in the working directory:
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/libs

Files in the working directory:
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample.dll
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/log4net.config
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample.deps.json
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample.pdb
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample.runtimeconfig.dev.json
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/appsettings.json
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample.runtimeconfig.json
/home/gridgain/w/ignitenet-kubernetes-example/ApacheIgniteNetKubernetesExample/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/appsettings.development.json

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,095][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] 

>>>    __________  ________________  
>>>   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/  
>>>  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/    
>>> /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/   
>>> 
>>> ver. 2.7.0#20181130-sha1:256ae401
>>> 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
>>> 
>>> Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org

[2019-04-03 17:29:02,096][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Config URL: n/a
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,110][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=8, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, igniteHome=/home/gridgain/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin, igniteWorkDir=/home/gridgain/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@3e58a80e, nodeId=f5a4c49b-82c9-44df-ba8b-5ff97cad0a1f, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=0, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=null, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$FirstConnectionPolicy@4cc8eb05, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, locAddr=null, locHost=null, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=0, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=null, shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=false, connectionsPerNode=1, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=2000, boundTcpPort=-1, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@51f116b8[Count = 1], stopping=false], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@19d481b, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@7690781, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@77eca502, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=null, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=60000, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=8, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=PlatformDotNetConfiguration [binaryCfg=null], binaryCfg=null, memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=DataStorageConfiguration [sysRegionInitSize=41943040, sysRegionMaxSize=104857600, pageSize=0, concLvl=0, dfltDataRegConf=DataRegionConfiguration [name=default, maxSize=6720133529, initSize=268435456, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=false, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=false, checkpointPageBufSize=0], dataRegions=null, storagePath=null, checkpointFreq=180000, lockWaitTime=10000, checkpointThreads=4, checkpointWriteOrder=SEQUENTIAL, walHistSize=20, maxWalArchiveSize=1073741824, walSegments=10, walSegmentSize=67108864, walPath=db/wal, walArchivePath=db/wal/archive, metricsEnabled=false, walMode=LOG_ONLY, walTlbSize=131072, walBuffSize=0, walFlushFreq=2000, walFsyncDelay=1000, walRecordIterBuffSize=67108864, alwaysWriteFullPages=false, fileIOFactory=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory@59af0466, metricsSubIntervalCnt=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity=-1, writeThrottlingEnabled=false, walCompactionEnabled=false, walCompactionLevel=1, checkpointReadLockTimeout=null], activeOnStart=true, autoActivation=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8, idleTimeout=0, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=null, commFailureRslvr=null]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,110][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Daemon mode: off
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,110][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] OS: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic amd64
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,110][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] OS user: gridgain
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,111][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] PID: 8539
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,111][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,111][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_144-b01 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.144-b01
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,112][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] VM total memory: 0.48GB
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,112][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Remote Management [restart: off, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,113][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Logger: Log4JLogger [quiet=false, config=/home/gridgain/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/config/ignite-log4j.xml]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,113][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] IGNITE_HOME=/home/gridgain/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,113][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true, -DIGNITE_QUIET=false]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,113][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] System cache's DataRegion size is configured to 40 MB. Use DataStorageConfiguration.systemRegionInitialSize property to change the setting.
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,119][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' dataRegion: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,122][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] 3-rd party licenses can be found at: /home/gridgain/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/libs/licenses
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,123][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Local node user attribute [service=ProductService]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,157][INFO ][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] Configured plugins:
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,157][INFO ][main][IgnitePluginProcessor]   ^-- None
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,157][INFO ][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] 
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,158][INFO ][main][FailureProcessor] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED]]]]
[2019-04-03 17:29:02,186][INFO ][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,195][WARN ][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,232][WARN ][main][NoopCheckpointSpi] Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,254][WARN ][main][GridCollisionManager] Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,293][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,430][WARN ][main][IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager] DataRegionConfiguration.maxWalArchiveSize instead DataRegionConfiguration.walHistorySize would be used for removing old archive wal files
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,444][INFO ][main][PartitionsEvictManager] Evict partition permits=2
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,593][INFO ][main][ClientListenerProcessor] Client connector processor has started on TCP port 10800
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,624][INFO ][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11211]
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,643][WARN ][main][PlatformProcessorImpl] Marshaller is automatically set to o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryMarshaller (other nodes must have the same marshaller type).
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,675][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Non-loopback local IPs: 172.17.0.1, 172.25.4.188
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,675][INFO ][main][IgniteKernal] Enabled local MACs: 0242929A3D04, D481D72208BB
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,700][INFO ][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Connection check threshold is calculated: 10000
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,702][INFO ][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locNodeId=f5a4c49b-82c9-44df-ba8b-5ff97cad0a1f]
[2019-04-03 17:29:07,844][ERROR][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries).
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:172)
```

(but that's expected)

Have you tried to moving `ignite-kubernetes` from `libs/optional/` to `libs/` instead of manually adding its JARs to classpath? Do you have anything else in your libs/?

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix this specific problem by listing all the JAR files in the Libs directory.

Comment: Actually, not exactly. I'm still experiencing the same error even with the above fix. I've set "-DIGNITE_QUIET=false" in JvmOptions but Ignite does not seem to run far enough to show the actual Classpath. The logs output quoted above is the only log output I get.

I did not load the `ignite-spring-data_2.0` submodule manually. Ignite is using the default set of JAVA files supplied with the Ignite .Net Nuget package + the three kubernetes JARs.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducer project out of it, post it somewhere?

Comment: Ok, I'll try in the beginning of the next week.

Comment: Hi @alamar I've created the repro project: https://github.com/alexavrutin/ignitenet-kubernetes-example  Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like it runs reasonable far with me (note that I don't have K8s so I'm not getting further)

Comment: When I start the project without Kubernetes, it also runs successfully. I get the above error only when I run the container under Kubernetes.

Comment: I wonder if it can be related to the version of Java which I install in the Docker container.

Comment: It should not. Maybe you have some leftovers in libs/?

Comment: Is it possible to list files in libs/ on k8s? Unfortunately I don't have k8s cluster to check.

Comment: I'll check and let you know later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Here's the list of files with the log (the log seems to be the same as before): https://gist.github.com/alexavrutin/72ab4a41d534330052145c8cc3c96eae

While I was preparing this dump, I noticed that the three ignite-kubernetes JARs did not copy in the K8s env, and I thought that this is the root cause of the problem. However, although now the JARs are being properly copied, nothing has changed.

Comment: I notice that 2 similar JARs exist in the libs dir -- can it be the problem? /app/libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/app/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar

I see that those duplicating files (along with a couple of other files) are being coming from the Apache Ignite Net Nuget package's Libs irectory.

Comment: I've limited the number of references in JvmClassPath to the absolute minimum with no repetitions but the same error remains: annotations-13.0.jar;cache-api-1.0.0.jar;commons-codec-1.11.jar;h2-1.4.197.jar;ignite-
core-2.7.0.jar;ignite-indexing-2.7.0.jar;ignite-kubernetes-2.7.0.jar;ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar;jack
son-core-2.9.6.jar;jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;/app
/libs/lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar;spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar;spring-jd
bc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar;spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @AlexAvrutin Judging from your stack trace you have DefaultListableBeanFactory from Spring 5. In Spring 4 line 727 of that class is empty but in Spring 5 it does indeed contain logger invocation. And it is true that in Spring 5 they moved that logger.
So something is still wrong with yout classpath, I just don't understand what. Can you unzip -l all jar's inside your Kubernetes to make sure none of them contain conflicting DefaultListableBeanFactory?

Comment: I wonder if it is worth for the guys responsible for the .Net version releases, to review the collection of JARs they are supplying in the Libs directory of the Nuget package. Maybe they are including multiple versions of the JARs by purpose and this is working fine in Windows. However, in Linux/Kubernetes env, this seems to cause issues.

Comment: Currently we have no code that is responsible for populating `libs/` on Linux/.Net. This means that any libs you have there are result of your own code.
However I'm not so sure what happens when your build env is Windows.

Comment: The docs instructs .Net developers to use the contents of the Libs folder supplied as a part of the Nuget package, and I am following that practice: 
https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/deployment#section-nuget-deployment

Comment: This will not happen on Linux/DotNetCore, maybe docs should be tweaked in this respect. Can you add `-verbose:class` to the list of JVM options and retry, share the log with us?

Comment: Done: https://gist.github.com/alexavrutin/3c1b7398e1ef54403596d8988029c043

I've also recreated the list of JARs from scratch (JvmClasspath is in the log for your reference).

Look like another class is not found: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView ?

Comment: Maybe I am getting something wrong (I'm not proficient in JAVA) but I don't find any mention of `com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView` (the missing class) in jackson-core-2.9.6 where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Finally, I've solved this problem. I've downloaded and added one more JAR: `jackson-annotations-2.9.6.jar`. This JAR was not in the list of JARs for the ignite-kubernetes module. Perhaps it is worth adding it. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your corrected logs it seems that you have stumbled on [IGNITE-10577](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-10577) issue. Indeed you will have to copy this dependency manually. I still wonder why you were seeing that error instead of the correct one:

```
SEVERE: Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:37)
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:291)
   at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubrnetesIpFinder.java:151)
```

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Maybe this is because I started off with the duplicated assemblies supplied with Ignite.Net? But I have no idea, really.